# Windows folder permissions being altered by Tomcat update installation

Tags: windows, tomcat, permissions

I am attempting to install an Apache Tomcat update but the install is altering the Tomcat folder permissions.
The folder is on a drive which is dedicated to my companies programs.

How do I retain windows permissions?
or apply its parent directory permissions down to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I address this pesky problem after installation.

1. Change the owner of the Tomcat installation folder to the user/group that should have access. (Right-click Tomcat installation folder [e.g. C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0]>> Properties>> Security tab>> Advanced button>> Click Change button)
2. Select boxes "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" and "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permissions from this object">> Click OK>> Confirm, click Yes.
3. Now, do the same for the Apache Software Foundation folder (e.g. C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation).
4. Lastly, in Services app>> Tomcat service properties>> Log On tab>> change log on as to "Local System account"